# 3d to 2d Coordinate trouble

Tags: c, coordinates, raytracing

Im attempting to write a very basic raytracer in C from the ground up. Im having some trouble getting the 2d coordinate from my 3d point in space.

I was able to shoot off the camera rays easily and accurately enough drawing the model on screen nicely. Now I am wanting to have a defined bounding box for the model on screen so i can quickly move over areas of the image that arent relevant to the rendering process.

The closest result ive had is better when the objects are closer to the camera. When I push the camera back ( incrementing cam->pos.z ) my bounding box starts to become way way off.

Ive seen a good dozen or so different formulas on stackoverflow that ive been experimenting/applying with but havent gotten them working successfully. If anyone can look at what im doing and offer some advice/correction that would be great.

My coordinates are y-up.

functions I am using to get the ray direction (seems to be working but thought it might be relevant):

```
#define FOV 55 // placeholder - should move to camera attr

double deg2rad(double degrees)
    {
        return degrees * M_PI / 180.0;
    }

    double rad2deg(double radians)
    {
        return  radians * 180.0 / M_PI;
    }

    void ray_fromPixel(Camera *camera, Resolution *res, Ray *ray, int x, int y) {
        ray->origin = camera->position;

        ray->orientation.x = x - (res->width/2);
        ray->orientation.y = (res->height / 2) - y;
        ray->orientation.z = -(res->height / 2) / tan(deg2rad(FOV*0.5));

        vector_Normalize(&ray->orientation);
    }
```

the 3d to 2d coordinate version (not working so well):

```
Coordinate coord_fromVector(Vector *v, Vector *cam_pos, int width, int height) {
    Coordinate screen;

    double hwidth = ((double)width) / 2;
    double hheight = ((double)height) / 2;

    double x_3D = v->x - cam_pos->x;
    double y_3D = v->y - cam_pos->y;
    double z_3D = v->z - cam_pos->z;

    screen.x = hwidth + (x_3D / z_3D) * hwidth; 
    screen.y = hheight - (y_3D / z_3D) * hheight;

    /* aspect ratio is commented out as its moving the box off screen */

    /*
    double aspect = screen.resolution.width / screen.resolution.height;
    if (aspect > 1.0) {
        screen.x /= aspect;
    } else {
        screen.y *= aspect;
    }
    */
    return screen;
}
```

Edit:Attempting to utilize some matrices...

```
    void matrix_projection(double ***m, double fov, 
                 double aspect,double znear, double zfar)
{
    double xymax = znear * tan(fov * M_PI / 360);
    double ymin = -xymax;
    double xmin = -xymax;

    double width = xymax - xmin;
    double height = xymax - ymin;

    double depth = zfar - znear;
    double q = -(zfar + znear) / depth;
    double qn = -2 * (zfar * znear) / depth;

    double w = 2 * znear / width;
    w = w / aspect;

    double h = 2 * znear / height;

    (*m)[0][0]  = w; (*m)[1][0]  = 0; (*m)[2][0]  = 0;   (*m)[3][0] = 0;
    (*m)[0][1]  = 0; (*m)[1][1]  = h; (*m)[2][1]  = 0;   (*m)[3][1] = 0;
    (*m)[0][2]  = 0; (*m)[1][2]  = 0; (*m)[2][2]  = q;   (*m)[3][2] = qn;
    (*m)[0][3]  = 0; (*m)[1][3]  = 0; (*m)[2][3]  = -1;  (*m)[3][3] = 0;
} 
//projection_matrix * modelview_matrix * world_coordinates

void matrix_multiply(double ***result, double ***m1, int r1, 
                        int c1, double ***m2, int c2)
{
    int i, j, k;
    for(i=0; i<r1; ++i)
        for(j=0; j<c2; ++j)
            for(k=0; k<c1; ++k)
            {
                (*result)[i][j] += ((*m1)[i][k]) * ((*m2)[k][j]);
            }
}

void matrix_allocate(double ***matrix, int rows, int cols)
{
    int x, y;
    *matrix = (double**) malloc(sizeof(double *) * rows);
    for (x=0; x < rows; x++) {
        (*matrix)[x] = malloc(sizeof(double) * cols);
        for(y=0; y < cols; y++) {
            (*matrix)[x][y] = 0.0;
    }
}
}

Coordinate coord_fromVector(Vector *v, Vector *cam_pos, int width, int height) {
    Coordinate screen;

    double hwidth = ((double)width) / 2;
    double hheight = ((double)height) / 2;

    double aspect = hwidth / hheight;

    double **proj; 
    matrix_allocate(&proj, 4, 4);
    double **model;
    matrix_allocate(&model, 4, 4);
    double **vmatrix;
    matrix_allocate(&vmatrix, 1, 4);

    vmatrix[0][1] = v->x;
    vmatrix[0][2] = v->y;
    vmatrix[0][3] = v->z;
    vmatrix[0][4] = 1;

    matrix_projection(&proj, 55, aspect, 1.0, 2000.0);

    model[0][0] = model[1][1] = model[2][2] = model[3][3] = 1;
    model[3][0] = cam_pos->x;
    model[3][1] = cam_pos->y;
    model[3][2] = cam_pos->z;

    double **proj_model;
    matrix_allocate(&proj_model, 4, 4);
    matrix_multiply(&proj_model, &proj, 4, 4, &model, 4) ;

    double **proj_model_v;
    matrix_allocate(&proj_model_v, 1, 4);
    matrix_multiply(&proj_model_v, &proj_model, 4, 4, &vmatrix, 1);

    screen.x = proj_model_v[0][0] / proj_model_v[0][3];
    screen.y = proj_model_v[0][1] / proj_model_v[0][3];
    return screen;
}
```

At this stage its still a long way off unfortunately.

Comment: I'd recommend using the same approach as used in graphics libraries (specifically, OpenGL's GLU, which has well-documented matrix construction). It documents [how a perspective projection matrix is constructed for `gluPerspective()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml) and you can figure out a ray direction [via `gluUnProject()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluUnProject.xml). Essentially, a ray goes from `winZ=0` towards positive `winZ`.

Comment: I'm confused what "3d to 2d coordinate" is supposed to do, though. Are you trying to do perspective projection?

Comment: yes. more or less. when i parse the model into memory i take note of what the 3d bounding box is for the model that ive loaded. Im looking to apply these to their respective screen coordinates and use them to skip over parts of the image that dont require rendering/raytracing.

Comment: Do you use the typical computer graphics approach of projection matrices and such? If yes, then see [`gluProject()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluProject.xml). You can use the `win{X,Y,Z}` equations there to help you out. `model` = modelview matrix, `proj` = projection matrix, and `view` is viewport info (integers `(x,y,width,height)` --- typically `(0,0,window_width,window_height)`).

Comment: What im using is what you see above. Im not using OpenGL, and yes I had already seen all of those pages. If i knew how to apply the information contained in those sites to what i have above i wouldnt be asking the question.

Comment: I'm not asking if you're using OpenGL, I'm asking if you're using the same approach for transformations and perspective projections. And for `gluProject()`, you just use those 3 equations to give you `win{X,Y,Z}`.

Comment: Can you be more clear about exactly what kind of input we're talking here about? Are these two vectors the position of the object and camera in your world? If so you're missing an important piece of information: the orientation of your camera.

Comment: That is true. It is missing from the above at the moment. It is 0,0,0. staring directly towards z. v1 is the point in 3d space im wanting to get the screen coordinates of and cam_pos is the camera position.